# Is it acceptable to being too subjective?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have asked [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2317/540) to know some rules related to Hat-trick in Cricket. Now [this user](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/647/sancho) is constantly asking me *What definition have you chose for Hat-trick?*. I already [told](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/hat-trick-rules-for-different-match-innings/2322#comment-4937) [him](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/hat-trick-rules-for-different-match-innings/2322#comment-4969) that in Cricket Hat-trick means taking three wickets in consecutive deliveries. But still he is being too subjective and asking me for a specific definition. Why should we use a specific definition when the meaning of Hat-trick is clear? Is this good behavior? Or am I missing something?

<sub>PS: I am not ranting. But my concern is that he is not getting my point what I want to say him.</sub>

Comment: Following the convo, it seems like the definition of "hat-trick" isn't **universally** clear (coming from one who is not knowledgeable in cricket)...and this is why said user asks his question...for clarity's sake. ie) "A hat-trick occurs in cricket when a bowler dismisses three batsmen with consecutive deliveries." vs. "Three successes of the same kind."

Comment: In a general sense, we are looking for quality. It is much more constructive to resolve misunderstandings/flawed perceptions than to make a user look [lazy and incompetent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612759/what-php-version-is-functionvaluevalue-supported-in#comment20405689_14612759). Opinions **will** differ, but that does not (and should not) distract away from the objectivity of any question asked.